# Restricting Kibana to TLSv1.2

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, kibana

What is the setting that needs to be set in the kibana.yml file (or other file) to restrict Kibana to TLSv1.2 over HTTP?

I believe that it uses TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2 by default. I need to restrict it to only TLSv1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `server.ssl.supportedProtocols`

`server.ssl.supportedProtocols: ["TLSv1.2"]` should be the desired option.